# Connection string to SQLOLEDB fails when password contains semicolon character

Tags: vb6, connection-string, ado, sqloledb

I am working on some legacy code (VB6) that connects to a database to retrieve some information. We have changed some passwords recently and now some accounts contain a `;` character in the password. For some connection strings this is not a problem, but for others it is. Ideally I would like a solution that will work for all Microsoft Server DBs, but at least it should support the two I'm using in my examples.

The connection strings I have that work are:

```vb
Dim connectionString = "Server=PROD;Database=Main;UID=User1;Password=""B3Z@2Q>N<;5"";PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;"
Dim connectionString = "driver={SQL Server};DATA PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=PROD;DATABASE=Main;PROVIDER=MSDASQL;UID=User2;Pasword=""?H7=9GHS?Y"";"
```

This allows me to connect using MSOLEDBSQL and SQLOLEDB. However, for the latter, passwords with semicolon such as User1's password fail and give an error saying

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

For example, see the below connection string that matches the second working example format but uses the UID and Password from the first working example:

```vb
Dim connectionString = "driver={SQL Server};DATA PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=PROD;DATABASE=Main;PROVIDER=MSDASQL;UID=User1;Password=""B3Z@2Q>N<;5"";"
```

I'm at my wit's end. I've been scratching my head and searching the internet for days to no avail.

Comment: `SERVER=` is [a part of](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/) the `MSOLEDBSQL` provider. If you are using the `sqloledb` provider like in your connection strings, the parameter that specifies the server name [is](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/) `Data Source=`, not `SERVER=`. Hence the error message that Data source name not found.

Comment: @GSerg the connection string works using `SERVER=` instead of `Data Source=` for the password without the semicolon using `sqloledb`, it's only failing when the password contains that character. I also just tried changing `SERVER=` to `Data Source=` in my VBS test connection script and it failed with the same error

Comment: You have both `DATA PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB` and `PROVIDER=MSDASQL` in the same connection string. The one that is used is `PROVIDER=MSDASQL`.

Comment: @GSerg and that works, at least for passwords that don't contain a semicolon. Removing the `PROVIDER=MSDASQL` and changing `SERVER=` to `Data Source=` still produces the same error

Comment: You cannot use `PROVIDER=MSDASQL` but say you are using `PROVIDER=sqloledb`. If you remove the `PROVIDER=MSDASQL`, then you are left with no `PROVIDER=` section at all. It's important to make up your mind about what providers you are actually using, as otherwise not only will you not be able to have the right sections in the connection string, but others won't be able to test it either. E.g. I just tested a semicolon password with `sqloledb` and it worked fine. So please provide [an MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a valid connection string.

Comment: @GSerg so then the question is actually how do I get passwords with special characters working with the `MSDASQL` provider? I couldn't find anything online about that either, all connection string samples I found use `PWD=` for the `MSDASQL` connection string

Comment: What do you get when you attempt to build the connection string using the properties rather than the pre-made string? I.e. having declared `Dim c as ADODB.Connection`, you first do `c.Provider = "MSDASQL"` (this refreshes the Properties collection), and after that `c.Properties("Password") = "B3Z@2Q>N<;5"`. Then what do you get in `c.ConnectionString`?

Comment: @GSerg Doing that shows the `ConnectionString` property as `Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password="B3Z@2Q>N<;5"` so I guess in theory it should just work how I had it similar to how it worked with a password that had no `;` character